# MKMapView clipsToBounds not working on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, ios6

I have a `MKMapView` with a transparent toolbar at the bottom. In order to show the `mapView` behind the toolbar I have `clipsToBounds` disabled:

```
self.mapView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

This used to work fine, but with iOS 6 it doesn't anymore. The map clips anyway (overlays don't by the way).

If I make the `frame` of my `mapView` bigger, the toolbar hides the "Legal" link of the map.

Any sugestions?

Thanks,
Jochen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: the legal View is a direct subview of the mapView. So I could just move it up a little.

```
UIView *legalView = nil;
for (UIView *subview in self.mapView.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) { 
        // Legal label iOS 6
        legalView = subview;
    } else if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        // google image iOS 5 and lower
        legalView = subview;
    }
}
legalView.frame = ...
```